# Wait all promises in a map function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to wait to read all my pictures in a map function

I tried this

```
let buffer = [];
// Folder of the dataset.
const rootFolder = './dataset'
console.log("Entering in folder dataset");
fs.readdirSync(rootFolder);
// For each folders
const files = fs.readdirSync(rootFolder).map(dirName => {
  if(fs.lstatSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName)).isDirectory()){
    console.log(`Entering in folder ${path.join(rootFolder, dirName)}`);
    // For each files
    fs.readdirSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName)).map(picture => {
      if(fs.lstatSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, picture)).isFile()){
        if(picture.startsWith("norm")){
          return fileToTensor(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, picture)).then((img) => {
            buffer.push(img);
          }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)});
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

Promise.all(files);
console.log(buffer);

async function fileToTensor(path) {
  return await sharp(path)
  .removeAlpha()
  .raw()
  .toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true });
}
```

But my buffer is still empty...

I know promises exist but I don't know how can I include them in map(map())

Thanks you :)

Comment: `Promise.all(files)` ?

Comment: Still empty :-(

Comment: `Promise.all(files).then(() => { console.log(buffer); });`..? You are mapping an array to a promise array, then calling `Promise.all` on the array, but you're not wrapping your code inside the then callback. I'm still not expecting it to work though, since `map` is sync, while you're working with async code. Is there any reason you're using `.map`? Besides, the `map` result is never returned.

Comment: `return fs.readdirSync`

Comment: Ok, reading the whole code again, there is **much** work to do here. I would entirely refactor the above code.

Comment: Briosheje No reason just I prefer this syntax ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor the above code to this:

```
let files = [];
// loop each dir.
fs.readdirSync(rootFolder).forEach(dirName => {
    // if it's a directory, procede.
  if(fs.lstatSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName)).isDirectory()){
    console.log(`Entering in folder ${path.join(rootFolder, dirName)}`);
    fs.readdirSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName)).forEach(picture => {
      if(fs.lstatSync(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, picture)).isFile()){
        // If lstatsync says it's a file and if it starts with "norm"
        if(picture.startsWith("norm")){
            // push a new promise to the array.
          files.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fileToTensor(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, picture)).then((img) => {
              buffer.push(img);
              resolve();
            }).catch((error) => {console.log(error); reject(error);});
          }));
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

// Resolve all promises.
Promise.all(files).then(() => {
    // Then do whatever you need to do.
    console.log(buffer);
}).catch((errors) => {
    console.log('one ore more errors occurred', errors);
});
```

Basically, here is what I did:

1. Removed `.map`, since it's not necessary in this context. Also, in your case, not all code paths returned a result, hence not every callback returned a result.
2. Pushed each needed item to the files array, which is a `Promise[]`.
3. Called `Promise.all` on the files array. Each resolved promise will push the result to the `buffer` array. I would've handled it in a different way, but still, this is the fastest I could think of.
4. Registered a callback on `Promise.all`, so that `buffer` will be defined.

As a side note, there are **a lot** of third party libraries that helps you to avoid having nested loops and promises looping the file system. I've just posted this to try giving something that could actually work from the existing code, despite an entire refactor would be clever here, and a preliminary analysis of available node libraries would also help to make the code easier to read and to mantain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a few advices:

1. DON't use arrow functions for anything you cannot put in a single line (they aren't intended for that and this wrecks readability)
2. Check that each callback you pass to .map() actually return something (first one doesn't. It seems you missed a `return` before inner `fs.readdir(..)...`.
3. Better try to name all functions (except arrow ones in the cases that they're good choice). This way not only I could name it to better identify them in the previous point but also stack traces would be much more readable and useful (traceable).

That being said, you are reading directories (and subdirectories) synchronously to finally return promises (I understand that `fileToTensor()` is expected to return a promise). It may not have a major impact on the overall execution time because I suppose actual file processings would be much more expensive BUT this is a bad pattern because you are blocking the event loop during the tree scan (so, if your code is for a server that needs to attend other petitions, you are pulling performance a bit down...).

Finally, as others already said, there are libraries, such as [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) that eases that task.

On the other hand, if you want to do it by yourself (as an understanding exercise) I myself implemented [my own library](https://github.com/bitifet/sats/blob/master/index.js) for the same task before knowing about *glob* which could serve you as a simpler example.

Comment: Thanks for advice :D

Answer (score 0):

Hye I've bit updated your code please go through once. It might be helpful :)

```
let fsReadDir = Util.promisify(Fs.readdir);
let fsStat = Util.promisify(Fs.stat);
let picturePromises = [];
let directories = await fsReadDir(rootFolder);
for (let dirIndex = 0; dirIndex < directories.length; dirIndex++) {
    let file = directories[dirIndex];
    let stat = await fsStat(path[pathIndex] + '/' + file);
    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        let pictures = await fsReadDir(path.join(rootFolder, dirName));
        for (let picIndex = 0; picIndex < pictures.length; picIndex++) {
            let stat = await fsStat(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, pictures[picIndex]));
            if (stat.isFile()) {
                if (picture.startsWith("norm")) {
                    let pTensor = fileToTensor(path.join(rootFolder, dirName, pictures[picIndex])).then((img) => {
                        buffer.push(img);
                    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
                    picturePromises.push(pTensor); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Promise.all(picturePromises);
console.log(buffer);

async function fileToTensor(path) {
    return await sharp(path)
        .removeAlpha()
        .raw()
        .toBuffer({ resolveWithObject: true });
}
```